# Decide $\{a^nb^n\mid n>0\}$ in log space

Tags: complexity-theory, decision-problem, space-complexity

Given $S = \{a^n b^n \mid n > 0\}$, show $S$ is deterministically decidable in log space.

Hint: to count up to $n$ you need $\log n$ bits.

This comes from some lecture notes at https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/OptimaNetSci/slides/ThangSept20.pdf

but they did not show how to prove it. Any ideas?  (Was posted in wrong section before)

Comment: Hint: give *any* algorithm deciding $S$. How much space does it take?

Answer (score 4):

The hint that you have pretty much solves the problem.
Essentially you need two counters; one for `a` and one for `b`.

1. If the first occurrence is not an `a`, you reject.
2. Start counting `a`s. You will encounter `n` of those, until the end of input, or you find a different character. When you stop reading `a`s, at that point you have `n` in binary. Essentially, every time you read an `a`, you simply perform addition in the counter that is used for counting `a`s.
3. If you have reached the end of input, or if the next character is not b, you reject.
4. Start counting `b`s in the same manner as you were counting `a`s until you reach the end of input or encounter a different character. You will read at most `n` `b`s, by checking every time that you read a `b` if you have read less than `n` characters. This is again straightforward because the two counters for `a` and `b` are in binary. If you read a different character you reject. If you reach the end of input after `n` `b`s, then you accept; otherwise reject (there is another character coming up - might even be a `b`).

Thus, we need O(log(n)) space.

Comment: Note that you could also just use one counter and start decrementing it when you reach the $b$s. In fact, you can do even better: if you have an extra tape symbol available, you can decide this language in zero extra space by just crossing off $a$s and $b$s in matched pairs.

Comment: You are right; two counters are used for illustration. One is enough. Of course I also agree with the second statement assuming that we have an extra tape symbol (i.e. a symbol that is guaranteed not to be part of the input).

Comment: @DavidRicherby Your "zero extra space" and "extra tape symbol" might be confusing in the context of log-space. Space complexity counts the space used in the working tape, where the input is not rewritten.

Comment: @HendrikJan Good point. This is why I try to avoid working at 10pm on Sundays!